# How to find the name of the currently selected media output?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, mediarouter

What is the correct way to retrieve the name of the currently selected media audio output on Android?

I have looked into the [Audio Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/AudioManager) and [Media Router](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/mediarouter) APIs, but not been able to see any way of retrieving which of the audio devices is the currently selected output.

I've seen that for example Spotify app has this capability:

[image: Spotify Screenshot with audio source shown]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this with wired devices but I did this for  Bluetooth devices like this-

```
BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager)   
                             getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

               bluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, listener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);

public final BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener listener = new  BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(int i, final BluetoothProfile      bluetoothProfile) {

        final TextView device = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.device);
        List<BluetoothDevice> b = bluetoothProfile.getConnectedDevices();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(BluetoothDevice getConnectedDevice : b){
            stringBuilder.append(getConnectedDevice.getName());
        }
       device.setText(stringBuilder); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int i) {
        final TextView device = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.device);
        device.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }
};
```

You can try this for Bluetooth devices, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private fun getOutputDeviceName(): String {
    val am = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        ?: return ""
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (am.isWiredHeadsetOn || am.isBluetoothScoOn || am.isBluetoothA2dpOn)
            return "Headset"
    } else {
        val devices = am.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS)
        for (device in devices) {
            if (device.type == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET || device.type == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADPHONES || device.type == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_A2DP || device.type == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_SCO) {
                return device.productName.toString()
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val mediaRouter = context.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE) as MediaRouter
                        // Assuming you want to check the route for media playback
                        val route = mediaRouter.getSelectedRoute(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO)
```

//route.name.toString() <- name